# Validação php só retorna um valor

Tags: php, html, mysql

A minha validação de login está retornando sempre o mesmo valor na minha variável $row.

Segue o código:

conexao.php

```
<?php
define('HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('USUARIO', 'root');
define('SENHA', '');
define('DB', 'login');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USUARIO, SENHA, DB) or die('Não foi possível conectar');
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = $query = "select usuario_id, usuario from usuario where usuario = '$usuario' and senha = md5('$senha')"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: cadastro.html');
    exit();
} else {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}
```

No meu if($row..) é sempre retornado o else, mesmo com o usuário cadastrado no banco de dados, ou seja, independente do usuário digitado, errado ou não, a função redireciona para index.html

Estrutura da tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: A conexão com o bd foi realizada com sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo o princípio que seu aquivo `index.html` é o arquivo que tem o formulário de login, você precisa informar ao elemento `<form>` para onde ele deve enviar os dados quando form submetido.
Você pode fazer isso usando o atributo [action](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) desse elemento.

Veja o código html com o atributo action apontando para sua pagina **login.php**

```html
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" />
    <input type="password" name="senha" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" />
</form>
```

**Nota** A tag `<form>` sem o atributo `action` sempre apontará para a própria página em que o form está inserido caso esse atributo seja omitido, por isso você sempre era redirecionado para ela e o arquivo `login.php` nem chegava a ser acionado.

Comment: Oi amigo, meu form está como escreveu, e mesmo assim com erro.

Comment: Você pode postar o conteúdo do arquivo index.html?

Comment: Descobri o erro. Quando o campo fazia a validação, ele estava buscando a senha na coluna usuário do banco de dados. No meu bd, troquei o nome das colunas usuário e senha, um pelo outro. Daí funcionou certinho.